# How to set roll angle of Camera when working with ArcGIS Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

According to the ArcGIS Javascript API reference for [Camera](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Camera.html), the properties that can be set include `fov`, `position`, `heading` and `tilt` but not the roll angle. How can I set the roll angle?

Since ArcGIS Javascript API uses WebGL for rendering, I have also tried to look into changing the roll angle using WebGL.   But due to my limited knowledge to WebGL, I have not found the way.  However, I trust that it is possible.  Grateful I someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Can you share why you would want to change the camera roll?

Comment: If it helps, we recently wrote a blog article about changing camera properties: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/js-api-arcgis/3d-gis/arcgis-api-for-javascript-camera-intro/

Answer (score 1):

Setting roll on the Camera is currently not possible.